# How to pass ViewModel to Index view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

Im using MVC 5 and EF 6.
There is a viewModel as below which I used it for create view:

```
public class LeadViewModel
{
    public Leads _leads { get; set; }
    public Addresses _addresses { get; set; }
    public Phones _phones { get; set; }
    public Emails _emails { get; set; }

    public SelectList EmployeesList { get; set; }
    public SelectList IndustryList { get; set; }
    public SelectList LeadSourceList { get; set; }
    public SelectList LeadStatusList { get; set; }

    public SelectList AddressTypeList { get; set; }
    public SelectList CityList { get; set; }

    public SelectList PhoneTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to pass some of its fields to Index view. How should I do that?

Here is more info about other tables:

1-Lead Class:

```
public partial class Leads
{
    public Leads()
    {            
        this.LeadAddresses = new HashSet<LeadAddresses>();
        this.LeadContacts = new HashSet<LeadContacts>();
        this.LeadEmails = new HashSet<LeadEmails>();
        this.LeadPhones = new HashSet<LeadPhones>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public string NamePrefix { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]       
    public string FullName { get { return NamePrefix + " " + FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int LeadStatusID { get; set; }


    public virtual Employees Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LeadEmails> LeadEmails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LeadAddresses> LeadAddresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LeadPhones> LeadPhones { get; set; }
    public virtual LeadStatus LeadStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Phones Class:

```
public partial class Phones
{
    public Phones()
    {            
        this.LeadPhones = new HashSet<LeadPhones>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PhoneID { get; set; }
    public int PhoneTypeID { get; set; }              
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }    
    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LeadPhones> LeadPhones { get; set; }
    public virtual PhoneTypes PhoneTypes { get; set; }
}
```

LeadPhones junction table:

```
public partial class LeadPhones
{
    [Key]
    public int LeadPhoneID { get; set; }
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public int PhoneID { get; set; }

    public virtual Leads Leads { get; set; }
    public virtual Phones Phones { get; set; }
}
```

In index view I want to display just:

```
Leads.FullName
Leads.Title
Leads.LeadStatus.Status
Leads.Employees.FullName
Leads.Phones.PhoneNo
Leads.Industries.Industry
```

Should I pass the viewModel to Index view from controller? If so, how?
And how should I use that in Index view?

Comment: So... the index view just needs a list of Leads? Why not just pass it an IEnumerable<Leads>? If it needs anything more, just create another view model.

Comment: Leads and LeadPhones and LeadEmails. I would create another viewModel but I do not know how to load and pass a viewModel to view.

Comment: It looks like LeadPhones and LeadEmails are already attached to the Leads object though a navigation property (the virtual keyword).

Comment: @br4d:  I think I have not explained well. There are "Leads", "Phones" table and a "LeadPhones" junction table. Now I want to display lead's name which is in "Leads" table and lead's phone which is in "Phones" table and they are connected in "LeadPhones" table.

Comment: Yes I understood that. You can either do what I suggest in my answer below or flatten them into a new viewmodel. Either way works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance for view model and pass it to the view

```
    LeadViewModel model = new LeadViewModel();
    //Populate model
    return View(model);
```

Comment: My problem is "Populate model" part. How should I populate the viewModel from database?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any extra info except the Lead and its related phones and emails then you can just pass it directly from entity framework:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    IEnumerable<Leads> model = db.Leads.Include(i => i.LeadPhones).Include(n => n.LeadEmails);
    return View(model);
}
```

In the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Leads>

foreach(Leads lead in Model)
{
    foreach(Phones phone in lead.LeadPhones)
    {
        <div>@phone.PhoneNo</div>
    }

    foreach(LeadEmails email in lead.LeadEmail)
    {
        // similarly with emails
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know the result.

Comment: I'm a rookie at MVC but this is not going to work. Because there is no "PhoneNo" in "LeadPhones" table. "LeadPhones" is just a junction table and contains only LeadID and PhoneID not the PhoneNo. PhoneNo is in "Phones" table. I don't know how to get PhoneNo of the specified lead.